# Moving the first word to the last position in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to move the first word to the last position in Java. But my program did not print the sentence. What could I be missing?

Here is my program:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FirstLast {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter line of text.");
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = kb.next();
        int last = s.indexOf("");
        System.out.println(s);
        s = s.sub string(0, last) ";
        System.out.println("I have rephrased that line to read:");
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: First, it won't compile...`s.sub string` isn't valid Java syntax.

Comment: Use int last = s.lastIndexOf(' ');

Answer (score 1):

```
    int last = s.indexOf(""); // Empty string, found at 0
```

should be

```
    int last = s.lastIndexOf(' '); // Char possible too
```

Comment: I got the answers but still negative impact. This is not a question?

Comment: Please do not take that personal, such small avalanches happen: from not-compilable, to marked question to rejection. It is an imperfect filtering mechanism to tackle the enormous mass of questions. IMHO you did have a valid question.

Answer (score 1):

You could  try something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter line of text.");
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = kb.nextLine(); // Read the whole line instead of word by word
    String[] words = s.split("\\s+"); // Split on any whitespace
    if (words.length > 1) { 
        //             v   remove the first word and following whitespaces 
        s = s.substring(s.indexOf(words[1], words[0].length())) + " " + words[0].toLowerCase();
        //                                                              ^   Add the first word to the end
        s = s.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1);

    }

    System.out.println("I have rephrased that line to read:");
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

You can do the spiting a bit simpler if you don't care about preserving the whitespaces

Output:

```
Enter line of text.
A aa  aaa    aaaa
I have rephrased that line to read:
Aa  aaa    aaaa a
```

For more info read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: let me try those. Thank you soooo much! I am totally clueless about programming. Just started out. Totally stressed me out last night.

Comment: You are awesome!! It worked! Thank you!! Output is:  Enter line of text. Without punctuation
Java is the language
I have rephrased that line to read:
is the language Java

Comment: How do i get the final output to show First letter as Uppercase?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your input is space-delimited strings, then you can swap the first and last positions like so.

```
String[] words = s.split(" ");
String tmp = words[0];  // grab the first
words[0] = words[words.length];  //replace the first with the last
words[words.length] = tmp;  // replace the last with the first
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read Scanner API document:

> A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern, which by default matches whitespace.

That is to say, you only get the first word using kb.next(). To fix it, you should get all words in a while loop or use line ending as delimiter.

[Scanner API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)